# How to check if a date range is in between another date range in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a date range which may be something like `((Date.today - 90)..Date.today)` and I want to check to see whether `(Date.today - 90)` is after the first value in another date range, and `Date.today` is before the final value in a date range. I've tried the following below

```
((Date.parse('25-12-2000')..(Date.parse('25-12-2020')).include?((Date.today - 90)..Date.today)
```

This returns false. I also get false if I replace `include?` with `member?` or `cover?`

How do I get this to return true? Syntax change or do I need to use a different method in Ruby?

Comment: Not the most effective approach, but you can do: `((Date.today - 90)..Date.today).all? { |d| (Date.parse('25-12-2000')..Date.parse('25-12-2020')).include? d }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`cover?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) to check if the date range covers both values:

```
range = Date.new(2000, 12, 25)..Date.new(2020, 12, 25)

range.cover?(Date.today - 90) && range.cover?(Date.today)
#=> true
```

or use [`begin`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html#method-i-begin) and [`end`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html#method-i-end) if you have two ranges:

```
range = Date.new(2000, 12, 25)..Date.new(2020, 12, 25)
other = (Date.today - 90)..Date.today

range.cover?(other.begin) && range.cover?(other.end)
#=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have two ranges `A = (a..b)` and `B = (y..z)` and want to know if `B` is fully covered by `A` then you can just ask if:

```
a <= y && z <= b
```

No need to build the ranges upfront.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just check the first and last date against the range:

```
range = (Date.today - 90)..Date.today)
validation_range = ((Date.parse('25-12-2000')..(Date.parse('25-12-2020'))
range.first > validation_range && range.last < validation_range.last
```

You could break this down even further, rather just the first and last dates of each:

```
start_date = (Date.today - 90)
end_date = Date.today
start_validation = Date.parse('25-12-2000')
end_validation = Date.parse('25-12-2020')
start_date > start_validation && end_date < end_validation
```

I'm not sure the naming's ideal and you could trim this down to one line if you wanted, but hopefully this serves for illustrative purposes. Also, you might want to use `>=` and `<=` though I'm not sure of whether the dates are inclusive.

This would avoid any potentially expensive loops.

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions!